# How to use DataContractSerializer to create xml with tag names that match my known types

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have the following data contract:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name="MyStuff")] 
public class MyStuff : Collection<object> {}

[DataContract(Name = "Type1")]
[KnownType(typeof(Type1))]
public class Type1
{
    [DataMember(Name = "memberId")] public int Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Type2")]
[KnownType(typeof(Type2))]
public class Type2
{
    [DataMember(Name = "memberId")] public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Which I serialize to xml as follows:

```
MyStuff pm = new MyStuff();

Type1 t1 = new Type1 { Id = 111 };
Type2 t2 = new Type2 { Id = 222 };

pm.Add(t1);
pm.Add(t2);

string xml;

StringBuilder serialXML = new StringBuilder();
DataContractSerializer dcSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyStuff));
using (XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(serialXML))
{
    dcSerializer.WriteObject(xWriter, pm);
    xWriter.Flush();
    xml = serialXML.ToString();
}
```

The resultant xml string looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyStuff xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <anyType i:type="Type1">
        <memberId>111</memberId>
    </anyType>
    <anyType i:type="Type2">
        <memberId>222</memberId>
    </anyType>
</MyStuff>
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to instead use the name of my known types rather than *anyType* in the xml tag?

I'm wanting it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyStuff xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <Type1>
        <memberId>111</memberId>
    </Type1>
    <Type2>
        <memberId>222</memberId>
    </Type2>
</MyStuff>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth are you doing this??

```
[DataContract(Name = "Type1")]
[KnownType(typeof(Type1))]
public class Type1
{
}
```

I don't think the `KnownType` attribute is needed here - it would be needed in polymorphism cases: if you have a method that returns `BaseType` and could return a derived type `Type1 : BaseType` in its place.

If you return `Type1` and you'll only ever really have `Type1` as the type, that knownType attribute is superfluous.

The second problem is this:

```
public class MyStuff : Collection<object> {
```

If you have a collection of `object` - it's a collection of potentially anything at all - so the serializer will use the `xs:anyType` to represent that.

Can't you introduce a base class type, make your collection a collection of that base type, and derive your two separate types from that base class?

Comment: I'm trying to write a xml file generator to spit out files that will be processed by a system I'm creating. This xml I'm needing has the approximate structure as listed in my question. Because I need to be able to have a collection of multiple types that aren't related, I've tried using a collection of object which I was hoping would allow for this. I'd be happy to remove the KnownType attribute, but without it the serializer throws an exception. I must admit I don't fully understand data contracts so I may need to do a bit of reading...