# Entities are not serializing using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I am trying to serialize Entities in my project.  I have a lot of them so i'm starting with just one at the moment.  The goal of my project is to create an audit trail with entity framework.  When I break at audit.newvalue = doc.root.tostring() the root is null.  I've been trying to follow every tutorial or q/a i find related to doing this, but everytime i get null.  Not sure what i'm missing here.

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Client
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

private Audit.DBAudit AuditTrailFactory(ObjectStateEntry entry, string userName)
    {
        var oc = this as IObjectContextAdapter; ;
        oc.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();

        Audit.DBAudit audit = new Audit.DBAudit();
        audit.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        audit.Entity = entry.EntitySet.Name;
        audit.User = userName;

        // set action type
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case System.Data.EntityState.Added:
                audit.ActionType = ActionTypes.I.ToString();
                break;
            case System.Data.EntityState.Modified:
                audit.ActionType = ActionTypes.U.ToString();
                break;
            case System.Data.EntityState.Deleted:
                audit.ActionType = ActionTypes.D.ToString();
                break;
            default:
                audit.ActionType = "F"; // fubar
                break;
        }

        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(entry.Entity.GetType());

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter();

        serializer.WriteObject(writer, entry.Entity);
        audit.NewValue = doc.Root.ToString();

        return audit;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CanCreateAudit()
    {
        FircrestModel.Client.Client client = new FircrestModel.Client.Client
        {
            FirstName = "billy",
            LastName = "jones",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1),
        };

        context.Clients.Add(client);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: is `entry.Entity` empty?

Comment: not it is not.  related not, my class client is much bigger than the example i am providing here. when i tried my test with this reduced version i got expected results. after refactoring how i was using the DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

after using this implementation of the DataContractSerializer, I got an expected output.  as i mentioned in a comment above, the client class is an abridged version.  i'm going to slowly go through my client class uncommenting properties until i find the one that seems to have broken the serializer.

[How to use DataContractSerializer to create xml with tag names that match my known types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912687/how-to-use-datacontractserializer-to-create-xml-with-tag-names-that-match-my-kno?rq=1)